# When the validateFields calls, logs 2 errors, when data are invalid (React, Antd)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, antd

I have a form in modal window, to which I send the Form.Items as props.
And then two errors are logged in console:

1. Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
   in Notification
2. Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {firstName, secondName, Login, Email}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
   in span
   in div
   in div (created by Notice)
   in div (created by Notice)
   in Notice (created by Notification)
   in AnimateChild (created by Animate)
   ...

```
 createModal = getFieldDecorator => (
    <Form layout="vertical">
      {generateInputFormItems(
        ['First name', 'Second name', 'Login', 'Email'],
        getFieldDecorator,
        this.state.defaultValueForForm, //initial
      )}
      <Form.Item label="Role">
        {getFieldDecorator('role', {
          rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please select the role' }],
          initialValue: this.state.defaultValueForForm
            ? // eslint-disable-next-line no-underscore-dangle
              this.state.defaultValueForForm.role && this.state.defaultValueForForm.role._id
            : undefined,
        })(
          <Select
            placeholder="Please select role"
            showSearch
            filterOption={(input, option) =>
              option.props.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
            }
          >
            {this.props.allRoles.map(({ _id, name }) => (
              <Option key={_id} value={_id}>
                {name}
              </Option>
            ))}
          </Select>,
        )}
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
```

Function, which creates my Form.Items from label

```
export function generateInputFormItems(labels, getFieldDecorator, defaultValues) {
  return labels.map(item => {
    const camelCaseItem = toCamelCase(item);
    return (
      <Form.Item key={item} label={item}>
        {getFieldDecorator(camelCaseItem, {
          initialValue: defaultValues ? defaultValues[camelCaseItem] : '',
          rules: [
            {
              required: true,
              message: `Please input the ${item}`,
            },
            {
              validator: item === 'Email' ? handleEmail : null,
            },
          ],
        })(<Input placeholder={`Input the ${item}`} />)}
      </Form.Item>
    );
  });
}
```

Forms in modal window 
formFields - method, which creates our Form (createModal)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Modal, Form } from 'antd';

export default Form.create({ name: 'form_in_modal' })(
  class extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
      const {
        visible,
        loading,
        handleOk,
        handleCancel,
        form,
        formFields,
        title,
        okText,
      } = this.props;
      const { getFieldDecorator } = form;

      return (
        <Modal
          visible={visible}
          confirmLoading={loading}
          title={title}
          okText={okText}
          onOk={handleOk}
          onCancel={handleCancel}
        >
          {formFields(getFieldDecorator)}
        </Modal>
      );
    }
  },
);
```

```
<FormsModal visible={isVisible}
          loading={creatingUser}
          handleOk={this.handleOk}
          handleCancel={this.handleCancel}
          formFields={this.createModal}
          wrappedComponentRef={this.saveFormRef}
          title={defaultValueForForm ? 'Edit' : 'Create'}
          okText={defaultValueForForm ? 'Edit' : 'Create'}
        ></FormsModal>
```

Comment: You not showing all relevant code, the object which holds `{name, description}` need to be refactored to `ReactElement`

Comment: it's the example of other form with other fields, sorry